# In Vim, what is the simplest way to join all lines in a file into a single line?

Tags: windows, vim

I want to join all lines in a file into a single line.  What is the simplest way of doing this?  I've had poor luck trying to use substitution (`\r\n` or `\n` doesn't seem to get picked up correctly in the case of `s/\r\n//` on Windows).  Using `J` in a range expression doesn't seem to work either (probably because the range is no longer in 'sync' after the first command is executed).

I tried `:1,$norm! J` but this only did half of the file - which makes sense because it just joins each line once.

Comment: See also "[How to delete the '\n' of every line in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6868335/254635)".

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Ah, I found the answer.

```
:1,$join
```

Works like a charm.

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comment:

```
:%join   -or-    :%j
```

...removes the range.

Comment: This can also be written as:
:%join

Comment: You may also want to use the gJ operation instead of j.  The gJ operation joins the lines without inserting or removing any spaces.

Comment: I self-answered this because I think this is much quicker than ggVGJ and slightly more elegant.

Comment: Note: %j! will join without spaces. (Add an exclamation mark.)

You can't use gJ with %.

Answer (score 141):

Another way:

```
ggVGJ
```

"`ggVG`" visually selects all lines, and "`J`" joins them.

Comment: Examples like this show why vim is so powerful.  "gg", "V", "G", "J", are all serparate commands.  excellent

Comment: As the accepted answer points out, `:%j` works, it's short, and doesn't require visual mode.

Answer (score 41):

You can do it with 3 keystrokes starting from normal mode:

```
:%j
```

- `:` enters command mode
- `%` refers to all lines in the file
- `j` executes the join command

Now it seems that this adds a space between the lines. I am not sure if you want this.

Comment: ```:%j!``` gets rid of the space.

Answer (score 17):

You can do it in three fewer keystrokes:

```
:1,$j
```

isn't ed grand?

Answer (score 11):

I’m surprised no one even mentioned the other way:

```
:%s/\n/ /
```

I am equally surprised that no one pointed out that the range `1,$` has a shorthand that’s written `%`.

(This doesn’t do the same thing as joining the lines, but depending on circumstances that may in fact be more appropriate.)

Answer (score 9):

Cryptic way:

```
qqqqqJ@qq@q
```

(the first three `q`'s clear the `q` register, the `qqJ@qq` records a macro to the `q` register that performs a Join, then calls `q`, and the last `@q` runs it.

Comment: Of course. :-p

http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/61no8/holy_shmoly_haskell_smokes_python_and_ruby_away/c02jz8x

Comment: Why would you want to clear the q register first, when you overwrite it anyway.  That's like doing a bunch of no-ops to make your command longer.

Comment: @Alf : Because if you have something in the q register, you will execute that macro while recording 'J@q'.