# Vim: make gq treat '.' as the end of a sentence

Tags: vim, latex, formatting

#### Related to [vim-how-to-reformat-a-set-of-lines-into-a-single-lines-if-the-line-is-a-single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450904/vim-how-to-reformat-a-set-of-lines-into-a-single-lines-if-the-line-is-a-single)

I'd like gq to treat a '.' as the end of a sentence in latex. Combined with a high value of `tw`, the intention is automatically reformat a paragraph into a list of lines.

*(FYI, this is a much nicer way to edit latex, if you are wondering)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I edit Latex, I use

```
:imap <Space><Space> <CR>
```

Don't think that it needs reformatting tricks.

---

[Paul Biggar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104021/paul-biggar) comments out that the similar solution works for people not used to putting two spaces at the end of each sentence:

```
:imap .<Space> .<CR>
```

Comment: Based on that, I can just make it `imap .<Space> .<CR>`. Thanks.

Comment: @Paul Biggar: I merged your idea into my answer.  You don't mind, do you?

Comment: @Pavel Shved: Of course not, I'd hoped you would. I didn't want to steal what's essentially your idea for my own answer :)