# How can I merge multiple lines into one line in Vim?

Tags: vim

For example, I want to merge such text:

```
CATEGORIES = ['Books',
        'Business',
        'Education',
        'Entertainment',
        'Finance',
        'Games',
        'Healthcare & Fitness',
        'Lifestyle',
        'Medical',
        'Music',
        'Navigation',
        'News',
        'Photography',
        'Productivity',
        'Reference',
        'Social Networking',
        'Sports',
        'Travel',
        'Utilities',
        'Weather',
        'All',  ]
```

into

```
CATEGORIES = ['Books', 'Business', 'Education', 'Entertainment', 'Finance', 'Games', 'Healthcare & Fitness', 'Lifestyle', 'Medical', 'Music', 'Navigation', 'News', 'Photography', 'Productivity', 'Reference', 'Social Networking', 'Sports', 'Travel', 'Utilities', 'Weather', 'All', ]
```

Comment: Why not simply perform a visual selection and then press `J`?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

In command mode:

```
[range]j[lines]
```

For example: here you want to do the whole buffer:

```
%j
```

If you just wanted to do 10 lines from the current cursor position:

```
j10
```

If you don’t want to replace the new lines with spaces, use <kbd>!</kbd> after <kbd>j</kbd>.

```
%j!
j!10
```

And for the uberfancy:

```
5j20
```

It would go to line 5, and join the next 20 lines.

Comment: vipJ would be more efficient here. Or, if on the first line before the "[", v%J would work as well. Or, anywhere in the text block, va]J

Comment: This should be upper case `J` and not lower case `j`.

Answer (score 60):

The most intuitive approach would be to use Vim visual line mode, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>. All you have to do is select the content you want to merge to one line, and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>.

Comment: I totally agree. This is the way I use it.

Comment: It seems on my mac I need to use RightShift for this to work, LeftShift selects the next line below adding it to the visual selection.

Answer (score 17):

Use the <kbd>J</kbd> (uppercase) key.  It will join the lines for you

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391710/in-vim-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-join-all-lines-in-a-file-into-a-single-line) thread for more join options, and see the help page.

Answer (score 7):

For that particular example, the following commands will work:

```
:1, 21 j
```

or

```
:%s/\n/ /g
```

Comment: I found ":%s/\n/ /g" is very slow with a large file, but ":1, 21 j" is super efficient.

Answer (score 3):

```
:g/\[/,/\]/j
```

Or

```
/^CATEGORIES

:v//-1j
```

And if you have:

```
edit "Komputer" 
    ala 
    ala 
next 
edit "FortiGate" 
    ala 
    ala 
next

:g/edit/,/next/j
```

Answer (score 2):

Or to join everything from the opening square bracket to the closing square bracket (assuming you have lots of these in your file) and leaving other lines intact,

```
:g/\[/,/\]/j
```

is quick and simple.