# How to delete the newline characters at the end of every line in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a huge file that I would like to format using Vim. For that, I would like to delete the newline characters at the end of every line.

For example,

```
I
want
this
to be
just one
line
```

should become

```
I want this to be just one line
```

I was thinking of doing it via the following command:

```
:%g/^/norm!‹a keyword that deletes the \n›
```

but I just don't know which keyword might work for that, to automate the pressing the <kbd>Del</kbd> key on every on every line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-for-a-newline-in-vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-for-a-newline-in-vim)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most idiomatic way of joining all lines in a buffer is to use
the `:join` command:

```
:%j!
```

(Remove the `!` sign if you want Vim to insert space between joined
lines. From the wording of the question I assume that you do not want
to add spaces.)

The same could be done interactively, if you prefer:

```
ggVGgJ
```

(Again, use `J` instead of `gJ` if you want to separate joined lines
with spaces.)

Another option is the `:substitute` command:

```
:%s/\n//
```

Comment: Man, every time I post an answer to a Vim question I get schooled :)

Answer (score 3):

`ggVGJ`

Broken down:

1. `gg`: move to line 1;
2. `V`: enter visual mode;
3. `G`: move to last line;
4. `J`: join selection to single line.

Comment: perfect! this works amazingly good. Still, is there a keyword to use like the manual delete?

Answer (score 2):

Why use Vim? You could easily use the following shell command:

```
tr -d '\n' < file
```

Comment: Yes I know, its just a curiosity thing :p

Comment: It is of course also possible to invoke tr directly from within vim, `gg!Gtr -d '\n'`.