# Run vim command on every line in a vim buffer

Tags: vim

I want to `JJ` on every line in the current vim buffer. As I have very huge file, it is not possible to manually run on every line. How can I tell vim to do this for me?
Basically I have a file which has data in single column. I want to convert it to three columns

```
a
b
c
```

to:

```
a b c
```

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [In Vim, what is the simplest way to join all lines in a file into a single line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391710/in-vim-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-join-all-lines-in-a-file-into-a-single-line)

Comment: @BimbaLaszlo the desired output of the question is not a single line.

Comment: @Kent yeah, i can see now, but should rewrite the example int he question to `a \n b \n c \n d` -> `ab \n cd`

Comment: @BimbaLaszlo not exactly. he is doing `xargs -n3`

Answer (score 12):

And another one:

```
:%norm JJ
```

See `:help :normal`.

Comment: Simpler than mine. I guess I was tricked into thinking `:global` by the question's title.

Answer (score 4):

Use Macro and [Normal mode command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3anormal).

```
qqJJq
```

Recoding `JJ` commands to `q`

```
uu
```

Define `q` macro. undo all.

```
:%norm! @q
```

apply `q` to entire document.

PS : I'm not good at english

Answer (score 2):

```
:g/^/join
```

joins consecutive lines (1+2, 3+4, and so on...) in the entire buffer. You can also supply a `[range]` to the `:global` command, which here is only used for its intelligent line handling; the `^` regular expression pattern matches *any line*.

To join *three* consecutive lines, use either

```
:g/^/.,.+2join
```

or

```
:g/^/join|join
```

(The former may give an error if the total amount of lines isn't divisible by 3; the latter avoids that.)